# ICommentEvent runs TWICE in ONE comment event Sitefinity

Tags: comments, sitefinity

I have these code, according to document from sitefinity:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Bootstrapper.Initialized += new EventHandler<ExecutedEventArgs>(Bootstrapper_Initialized);
    }

public void Bootstrapper_Initialized(object sender, ExecutedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.CommandName == "Bootstrapped")
        {
            EventHub.Subscribe<ICommentEvent>(evt => CommentsEvent.CommentEventHandler(evt));
        }
    }
```

And the handler:

```
public static void CommentEventHandler(ICommentEvent evt)
    {
        // My code here
    }
```

The problem is this handler always runs twice when a comment event happens (post a comment or approve a comment).

Could you please tell me why this happens and any possible way to avoid this? (I don't believe static boolean is a good idea).

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

ICommentEvent is a base interface that is implemented by multiple events such as ICommentCreatingEvent, ICommentCreatedEvent, ICommentUpdatingEvent, ICommentUpdatedEvent and some others.

In your case it is fired twice due to firing of both ICommentCreatingEvent and ICommentCreatedEvent.

You can subscribe to just one of them and it should fire just once.